# ellipsize for the canvas text in android

Tags: android, android-canvas

**What i am trying to do**: I am trying to set `...` after 7 characters in canavs for text

**How to achieve this ?**

```
private void drawText(Canvas canvas, float tmpAngle, float sweepAngle, String mStr) {
        float cx = (mRadius) / 2 + mPadding;
        float cy = (mRadius) / 2 + mPadding;
        float radius = mRadius / 2 + mPadding;
        float x = cx - radius + (mPadding * 2);
        float y = cy;
        float textWidth = radius - (mPadding * 10);
        TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
        textPaint.set(this.mTextPaint);
        textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        Typeface plain = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/AvenirLTStd-Heavy.otf");
        Typeface bold = Typeface.create(plain, Typeface.BOLD);
        textPaint.setTypeface(bold);

        float angle = tmpAngle + sweepAngle / 2;

        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(180+(angle), cx, cy); // +180 for start from right
        canvas.drawText(mStr, x, y, textPaint);
        canvas.restore();
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at the [`TextUtils.ellipsize()` methods](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#ellipsize(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.text.TextPaint,%20float,%20android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt)).

Comment: if original text size > 7 take a substring of first 7 characters of original text, add `...` to it

Comment: Wait a second. Why do you say "after 7 characters"? If it's always 7 characters, then I might not understand what you're asking. In that case, can't you just grab the first 7 characters, and append the ellipsis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
// textPaint attributes
CharSequence ellipsizedText = TextUtils.ellipsize("Your text", textPaint, width, 
TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
canvas.drawText(ellipsizedText, 0, ellipsizedText.length(), x0, y0, textPaint);
```

But in your case you need it after 7 characters, better just check the text length and append `...` after the text.